# how to use pure flatpickr in react?

Tags: reactjs, flatpickr

I'm new in reactJS, and I am trying to use pure **flatpickr** (https://flatpickr.js.org , NOT react-flatpickr)
Below is my current code. Any help on how to implement it properly?

---

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import flatpickr from "flatpickr"

export default class Datepicker extends Component<IProps> {

  public render() {
    flatpickr(".datepicker")
    return (
        <div>
           <input type="text" className="datepicker" />
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`flatpickr` requires a node or selector passed into it. In React, for referring to the DOM, we use a `ref`

For handling events and providing other options, you can use the second argument for options.

Here is a demo:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.datePicker = React.createRef();
  }
  onChange(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    console.log(selectedDates);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    flatpickr(this.datePicker.current, {
      onChange: this.onChange
    });
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <input type="date" ref={this.datePicker} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">

<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Example with hooks & Typescript (I had to use `useCallback` and `useRef` to make it work):

```
// Or configure the styling elsewhere.
import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css';

import flatpickr from 'flatpickr';
import { Instance } from 'flatpickr/dist/types/instance';

export default function Comp() {
  const fp1 = useRef() as MutableRefObject<Instance>;

  const inputRef = useCallback((node) => {
    if (node !== null) {
      fp1.current = flatpickr(node, {});
    }
  }, []);

  return (<input type="date" ref={inputRef} />);
}
```